# how do i get notified from buddy image change Xmpp android

Tags: java, android, xmpp

I am trying to develop an Xmpp client and displaying buddylist with images.I am storing images in cache directory for quick retrieval and unnesscary network usuage.The problem here is if the buddy has changed his image  how do i get notified to fetch the new image from the server ,not from the local cache. 
Please suggest.

Im using asmack api.

Comment: which api you are using for android ? Are you using asmak api?

Comment: thanks.question updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static XMPPConnection connection;

// If any changes occured in buddylist
connection.getRoster().addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {

            @Override
            public void presenceChanged(Presence arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {

            }
        });
```

**Fetch UserLIst**

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getUserList() throws Exception {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        if (isConnectionAlive() || reConnectAndAuth()) {
            Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
            Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
            for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                String avatarPath = "";
                VCard vCard = new VCard();
                try {
                    vCard.load(connection, entry.getUser());
                    vCard.getExtensions();
                    byte[] b = vCard.getAvatar();
                    Bitmap avatar = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(vCard.getAvatar(), 0, b.length);
                    avatarPath = savaAvatar(avatar, entry.getUser());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
                user.put("name", entry.getName());
                user.put("userid", entry.getUser());
                user.put("statusMsg", "" + entry.getStatus());
                user.put("user_avatar", avatarPath);
                user.put("status", "" + connection.getRoster().getPresence(entry.getUser()).isAvailable());
                userList.add(user);
            }
        }
        return userList;
    }
```

Comment: so,basically when user image is updated,ill be notified in entriesUpdated  ?

Comment: I updated image of roster but not get confirmation entries Updated may I know in which method it goes when roster image updated if I am not wrong than it will go in onPresence Change

Comment: but this wrong way because if we just simply update status to online to away or whatever than that time also it comes there so each time we fetch image using v-card to check image  was updated or not any other way is possible for it?